# Trying to code for user login authentication in express, not able to login from using express-session in node

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, express-session

I am trying to write a code for user login authentication in express using express-session

This is my accounts.js api

```
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
.use(bodyParser.json())
.use(session({ secret: 'hcdjnxcds6cebs73ebd7e3bdb7db73e' }))
.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/login.html');
})
.post('/login', function (req, res) {
        var user = {
            username : req.body.username,
            password : hash(req.body.password)
        };
        var collection = db.get('users');
        collection.findOne (user, function (err, data) {
            if (data) {
                req.session.userId = data._id;
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                res.redirect('/login');
            }
        });
})
.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.session.userId = null;

        res.redirect('/');
})
.use(function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.session.userId) {
            var collection = db.get('users');
            collection.findOne({ _id : new ObjectId(req.session.userId)}, function (err, data) {
                req.user = data;
            });
        }
        next();
});
```

module.exports = router;

And this is my server.js code

```
var express = require('express'),
    api         = require('./api'),
    users       = require('./accounts'),
    app         = express();

app
    .use(express.static('./public'))
    .use('/api', api)
    .use(users)
    .get('*', function (req, res) {
            if (!req.user) {
                res.redirect('/login');
            } else {
                res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/main.html');
            }
    })
    .listen(3000);
```

My problem is, in **server.js**,  **req.user** is getting null value that's why i am not able to login. But in **account.js** req.user getting user data which is not reflecting in server.js.

Again, if in **accounts.js**, I am placing **next()** inside the **if (req.session.userId)** statement, I am able to get user data in server.js but it creating problem in logout.

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `accounts.js` is executing `next()` before your collection query returns, so it makes sense that your req.user is undefined in your middleware later on. To fix it, try this:

```
.use(function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.session.userId) {
            var collection = db.get('users');
            collection.findOne({ _id : new ObjectId(req.session.userId)}, function (err, data) {
                req.user = data;
                next();
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
});
```

As a side note, you're very much reinventing the wheel here by implementing user login yourself. I would reccommend taking take a look at [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) for doing user login like this.

Comment: hey @andrew, i tried your suggestion, now it sending request on server and remains "pending..." forever

Comment: hey @andrew, thanx it's done. I frogot to add another next inside if(). Working now. And i will surely look into pasport too

Comment: Following the note about re-inventing the wheel, I would suggest that you check out a hosted user management solution such as [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) Disclaimer: I work there.  We have a great [Express integration](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express)